# MethodNotAllowedHttpException when using Route::delete

Tags: laravel

I don't know why I get this

[image: This is the image]

I tested the route with

```php
Route::delete("/attachments/{url}","TrixAttachmentController@destroyAttachment");
```

> localhost:3000/api/v1/attachments?url=hDXtilCleTWc6WyiMeWpp9O0xIx3cRyJuEwVPxzL.jpeg

```php
public function destroyAttachment($url){
        dd($url);
}
```

still i get it

Comment: change this `localhost:3000/api/v1/attachments?url=hDXtilCleTWc6WyiMeWpp9O0xIx3cRyJuEwVPxzL.jpeg` to `localhost:3000/api/v1/attachments/hDXtilCleTWc6WyiMeWpp9O0xIx3cRyJuEwVPxzL.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

```php
localhost:3000/api/v1/attachments?url=hDXtilCleTWc6WyiMeWpp9O0xIx3cRyJuEwVPxzL.jpeg
```

here `?url` it shows it now using `get` request

call this route via delete method

can you show form

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Route::delete`, the request is expecting a `POST` request with a method of `DELETE`.

If you are hitting the route in the browser using a `GET` request, this is the sort of error that will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the route in a browser you need to change that.
Make sure you are calling it on a form using DELETE verb.